# Find the parametric equation of the following parabola?

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, parametric

It doesn't give me $2$ equations this time just $1$ and I have no clue what to do;

$y^2 = 4x$

ANSWER IN BOOK:
$x = t^2, y = 2t$

Comment: Do you see why the book's answer works (i.e. if you plug $t^2$ in for $x$ and $2t$ in for $y$)?

Comment: You can't *solve* it. $x=t,y=2\sqrt t$ is also an answer.

Comment: I suppose it's a fairly nice parametrization, but as @Shahar points out, not unique in any obvious way.  It does allow $y$ to be negative in a natural way, whereas Shahar's parametrization needs a restriction $x \ge 0$ and yields only those $y \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=s$, put it into equation $y^2=4x$, you get:

$$s^2=4x$$

So:

$$x=\frac{s^2}{4}$$

You have parametric equation $x=\frac{s^2}{4}, y=s$. If you put $s=2t$ you get the same as in answer book.